# Floating Point Exception Caused By rand() In c++

Tags: c++, floating-point-exceptions

I have an issue that I can't seem to solve. I am randomly generating numbers in order to determine if my numbers are relativity prime.

Here is the function that gives me a Floating Point Exception:

```
bool modularExponentiationTest(unsigned long long exponent, unsigned long long modulus)
{
    short index = 0;
    unsigned long long base;
    unsigned long long result;

    do
    {
            result = 1;
            base = rand() % exponent; // <--CAUSED BY THIS

            while (exponent > 0) 
            {
                if (exponent & 1)       
                        result = (result * base) % modulus;
                exponent >>= 1;
                base = (base * base) % modulus;
            }

            if (result != 1)
                return false;
    }while(++index < 10);

    return true;
}
```

I did seed random in a different function by doing the following:

```
 srand(time(NULL));
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Which "floating point exception" is generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're shifting `exponent` to the right in the while loop until it reach 0.
So the second time you reach `base = rand() % exponent;` `exponent` is 0 and you have a division by 0

Comment: Well spotted, `exponent` is being downshifted to zero, and there's no guard against it being zero.

Comment: Good catch. Make your arguments const. Altering pass by value arguments inside of a function hides this sort of bug. Check for zero just before performing the modulus in each case.

Comment: Thanks very much! I just didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

Is the value of `exponent` zero? If so, that a divide-by-zero exception right there.

Comment: You should probably check both the modulus and exponent variables for zero since you modulus with both of them.

Comment: @Alex you could be more helpful - what is the exception generated and what is the value of both `rand()` and `exponent`?